# Can't install DMD 2.060 on OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, d, dmd

I am planning to try D for the first time in my life. I have a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard).

I went on the D downloads page and clicked on the link for the dmd 2.060 installer for OS X. I opened it and double clicked on the "DMD2.pkg" file within it. The installer came up with some text including a line that read "This package is intended for Mac OS X Leopard (10.5) only.". I tried to find a version for OS X 10.6 but I couldn't, so I ignored the warning and clicked "Continue".

I clicked through the agreements and questions, and then when it finished, the installer gave this message:

> The installation failed. The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

Someone on the forums suggested running the Console app when trying to install D. I tried that and got these messages:

```
9/17/12 7:33:35 PM  Installer[19715]    PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-api.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:35 PM  Installer[19715]    PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-bin.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:35 PM  Installer[19715]    PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-gui.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:35 PM  Installer[19715]    PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-kext.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:35 PM  Installer[19715]    PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-profiles.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:35 PM  Installer[19715]    PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-startup.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:54 PM  installd[19720] Starting
9/17/12 7:33:54 PM  installd[19720] uid=501, euid=501
9/17/12 7:33:54 PM  installd[19720] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-api.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:55 PM  installd[19720] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-bin.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:55 PM  installd[19720] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-gui.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:55 PM  installd[19720] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-kext.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:55 PM  installd[19720] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-profiles.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:55 PM  installd[19720] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-startup.pkg
9/17/12 7:33:57 PM  com.apple.installd.user[19720]  Permission denied
9/17/12 7:33:57 PM  Installer[19715]    The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
```

I [asked about it](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/yrcyfaalimocuovsvgqo@forum.dlang.org#post-ifqtxadrqpkjeyrpwfjn:40forum.dlang.org) on the digitalmars.D.learn forum. I am not sure if that was the most appropriate forum but I put it there because I am just starting to learn. I also filed a bug report on their tracker. You can see the [bug report](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=8682) or the [automatically-generated post on digitalmars.D.bugs](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/bug-8682-3@http.d.puremagic.com/issues/) but neither has gotten any responses yet.

Someone suggested using a 3rd-party program named DVM but I am feeling kind of reluctant about it. I don't see why I have to install a 3rd-party program, which is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation or on the download page AFAIK, just to install the compiler.

Does anyone know why this is happening or what I am supposed to do about it?

**EDIT:** Someone mentioned "vpnclient" in the comments. I used to have Cisco VPNClient installed for my previous job. <strike>However, I haven't had any use for it in over a year and I deleted it several months ago, at least.</strike> I don't remember the details of what version but if anyone needs to know, I can try to deduce that the next time I have access to my home computer.

**EDIT 2:** The above comment is partially wrong. I still have Cisco VPNClient 4.9.01.0180 on my computer, even though I haven't used it in over a year.

**EDIT 3:** I tried deleting VPNClient and I am still having the same problem. I still don't know for sure whether VPNClient has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: maybe you need to install vpnclient first...

Comment: Why would I need to install vpnclient?

Comment: I think that may have something to do with this problem. See my comment above.

Comment: You might try using gdc instead of dmd as well (it's slightly out of date at 2.057, but as I understand it builds much faster binaries): https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/wiki/Home#!building

Comment: I am sort of thinking about it but I am still wondering why I am having this problem. If DMD is so buggy it can't be installed, then why aren't other people complaining about it?

Comment: It looks to me like the vpnclient stuff is just warning messages, not errors, and is not the problem here. The real problem seems to be `com.apple.installd.user[19720]  Permission denied`. Perhaps try installing as root?

Comment: How can I install as root? I tried looking on Google but the results were somewhat vague.

Comment: use sudo (just like in linux)

Comment: I tried `cd /Volumes/DMD2/` then `sudo ./DMD2.pkg`, then I entered my password, but I got an error saying "sudo: ./DMD2.pkg: command not found". Am I doing this right?

Comment: I tried running `sudo open ./DMD2.pkg` and I was able to start the installer, but when I tried to install DMD, I got the same error as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the Mac version, but you can probably use D the easiest way I prefer on other platforms: just grab the zip and use it in place.

https://github.com/downloads/D-Programming-Language/dmd/dmd.2.060.zip

unzip it anywhere, then use it directly from the unzipped folder.

from your console

```
$ wget https://github.com/downloads/D-Programming-Language/dmd/dmd.2.060.zip
$ unzip dmd.2.060.zip
(then create your hello.d)
$ dmd2/osx/bin/dmd hello.d
```

Should work to produce your executable. I wouldn't bother with any fancier installation, it seems to cause more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: This is the best (in fact, the only) answer I have seen so far. I haven't tried it but it seems reasonable. I would prefer something that just lets me type `dmd` like I can type `gcc`, without having to fiddle with my PATH environment variable but if I don't get a better answer, I will award the bounty to you.

Comment: On my linux box, I use a little wrapper script in the main path:

    $ cat /usr/bin32/dmd
    #!/bin/bash
    exec /home/me/d/dmd2/linux/bin32/dmd $*

Of course fix up the paths, but then you can just type dmd while keeping the actual files wherever you want.

EDIT: ugh it doesn't seem to preserve lines, but it is just a one line wrapper.

Comment: I think I can figure it out. I will try it when I have time. Thank you.

Comment: One minor question: should the `$*` be `"$@"`? It looks like the `$*` may cause problems when trying to pass multiple arguments to dmd but I am not sure.

Comment: mikez302, for what you ask you will need an OSX installer that will setup your PATH as well... AFAIK such thing is not available on MacOSX, but hey, it is an open-source project, you may contribute and make a nice installer for MacOSX! ;)

Comment: idk, I've used the $* for a long time and never had a problem with it. But whatever works.

Comment: I am not sure if I would be the right person to contribute. I don't know much about OS X installers and I have never actually used D in my life. If I was more experienced, I would give it a try but I think there are other people who know more about this subject matter than I do.

Comment: I tried your idea and it worked. I was hoping to get the broken installer fixed or replaced with something that is not broken but I am glad to get something that works, at least for myself.

Comment: not much I can do there but I posted it to the D development newsgroup so maybe someone else will be able to fix the installer: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/hledprrajqbyhsvbxvou@forum.dlang.org#post-hledprrajqbyhsvbxvou:40forum.dlang.org

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18386187/dmd-2.060-osx-installer.zip
I got that file from the Mac installer's author. He rebuilt it on a newer mac and thinks it might work better. I don't have a Mac though so  I can't test myself.

Comment: I tried the zip and overall it mostly worked fine. I had some problems with rdmd but at least I have a compiler that works. Thank you.